# Redirect the fragment when click on button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using this code for replacing the fragment but there is a problem, it's not replacing the old fragment it just override on old fragment so please tell me what is the problem here.

```
public void selectFrag1(View rootView) {
        Fragment frag;

        if (rootView == findViewById(R.id.startup1)) {
            frag = new S_SignupFragment();
        } else {
            frag = new F_SignupFragment();
        }
        FragmentManager fragManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = fragManager.beginTransaction();
        fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_signup,frag);
        fragTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Use FrameLayout and its backgroundColor as white

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    fr = new FragmentOne();
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_place,fr);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

if you use same code then add this before call first button setonclicklistner

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you pass the parent view, that is going to hold your fragment on the line  `fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_signup,frag);` ?
For `fragmentTransaction.replace(...,...)` you need to specify a container for your fragment and the fragment itself. Check where does your `R.id.fragment_signup` directs. More information you could find in this SO question: [Unable to replace fragment on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24858383/unable-to-replace-fragment-on-button-click)

Comment: sorry before give me negative mark check your answer is good for me or not because it not solve my problem if I have points then I can also give you negative marks for this answer

Comment: I don't give negative marks. Please don't judge people if you don't know the reality!

Comment: yes I am definately sure and now I figerout my solution.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean in the last comment, but okay